# Elliptic deformation of the second Chern class

Tags: elliptic-curves, algebraic-k-theory, chern-classes

Second Chern class 
$$c_2 \in H^4(BGL,\mathbb{Q}(2))$$
admits a nice presentation using dilogarithm. The five term relation in this setting becomes a cocycle condition (details can be found [here](https://gauss.math.yale.edu/~ag727/4821)). Dilogarithm admits a natural deformation: elliptic dilogarithm. Is it related to some sort of elliptic Chern class?

Comment: There are motivic cohomology classes associated to the elliptic (or abelian) polylogarithms (see e.g. https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1999.088). Could they serve as definitions of Chern classes for an abelian scheme $A \to S$?